# Flask-Moment Check if Time is More Than 24 Hours Ago

Tags: python, flask, time, jinja2, momentjs

I would like to check if a time is more than 24 hours old with flask-moment. I have a utc time, which I pass to the HTML page. If the local time got from the utc time is less than 24 hours old, I want to be able to do something.

ex:

```html
{% if moment(utc_time) > 24 hours old %}
    do something
{% else %}
    do something
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a solution should look something like `now - then > '1 day'`. Since `utc_time` is a Python `datetime.datetime` object, it should be something like `datetime.utcnow() - utc_time > timedelta(days=1)`.

That means passing `utc_time`, the function `utcnow` and the object `timedelta(days=1)` to Jinja, and then rendering the template like so:

```py
{% if utcnow() - utc_time > one_day %}
    do something
{% else %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```